# Why does SWI-Prolog invent f/2 given only f/1?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, prolog-dif

SWI-Prolog 7.6.4:

```
?- dif(X, f(Y)), X=f(a).
X = f(a),
dif(f(f(a), Y), f(f(Y), a)).
```

Note that I use `f/1` in the query, but the constraint is on `f/2`. It's not wrong, but seems rather circuitous. Why doesn't Prolog return

```
?- dif(X, f(Y)), X=f(a).
X = f(a),
dif(Y, a).
```

Comment: seems a bug... sorry I haven't a constructive answer, most probably you should post on SWI-Prolog discourse. Jan W. always provides fast and accurate analysis and patches

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `f` in the printed constraint has nothing to do with your `f`. It's just a placeholder to keep subterms together:

```
?- dif(X, incal(Y)), X=incal(a).

X = incal(a),

dif(f(incal(a), Y), f(incal(Y), a)).    <--- residual constraints, not yet resolved
```

The above meaning just that:

- `incal(a)` must stay different from `incal(Y)`; and
- `Y` must stay different from `a`

Yes, you could simplify that but ... when does one know whether optimization will cost less than one will gain?

Comment: I see. Still strange though. It could have listed both constraints (or just the latter) without inventing `f/2`.

Comment: @MaxB I suppose this is just a way to avoid extraneous code or eke out some speed somewhere.